# Not able to install Commercial paper chaincode which is shown in documentation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

docker exec cliMagnetoCorp peer chaincode install -n papercontract -v 0 -p /opt/gopath/src/github.com/contract -l node .

above line is mentioned in the fabric documentation https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.html

when i run this then its giving below error

```
 Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
 chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error installing chaincode code
 papercontract:0(chaincode
 /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/papercontract.0 exists))
```

my question is how does `/opt/gopath/src/github.com/contract` come from in your documentation. its never mentioned anywhere.
Moreover,

```
  ./../../../../organization/magnetocorp:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
```

its written in docker-composer.yml. how /opt path is related and connected here ?

Comment: Hi - it says `papercontract.0` already exists on your peer..that means you've already installed that version of the contract.  So try instantiating the smart contract on the channel per the instructions. If you've changed the contract, but up the version - see upgrade example https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchaincode.html?highlight=peer%20chaincode%20upgrade#peer-chaincode-upgrade-example

Comment: The path you mention is explained under the 'Install Contract' section. GOPATH is explained under https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#install-instantiate-chaincode